# Using .mli files and Map

Tags: dictionary, types, interface, ocaml

I've read some similar questions and some online examples, but I still don't know how to write an `.mli` file in this particular case.

In my project, I use a general map module with int keys, which then I specialize depending on the values I want to store in. Let's say I want to use it to store pairs, so I have a file like this:

`file dataStr.ml:`

```
module IntOrder =
   struct
      type t = int
      let compare = Pervasives.compare
   end

module IntMap = Map.Make( IntOrder )

type couple = int * int
(* pretty names *)
type int2couple = couple IntMap.t
module Couples = struct type t = int2couple end
```

A file using this submodule would be:

`file useMap.ml:`

```
open DataStr

let use k m =
   IntMap.add k ((Random.int 6), (Random.int 8)) m
```

with interface:

`file useMap.mli:`

```
open DataStr

val use : int -> Couples.t -> Couples.t
```

So far, so good.

Let's now suppose that I want to expose submodule `Couples`, but not type `int2couple`. I would then write this interface:

`file dataStr.mli:`

```
module IntMap : Map.S with type key = int

module Couples : sig type t end
(*
I'd like to avoid the redundancy of using
module Couples : sig type t = (int * int) IntMap.t end
*)
```

Problem is, if I do add this interface, I get this compile error:

```
Error: The implementation useMap.ml does not match the interface useMap.cmi:
       Values do not match:
         val use :
           DataStr.IntMap.key ->
           (int * int) DataStr.IntMap.t -> (int * int) DataStr.IntMap.t
       is not included in
         val use : int -> DataStr.Couples.t -> DataStr.Couples.t
```

Is there a way to write an interface that lets me do what I want to do, other than the "redundant" one in the comment?

Comment: If you encapsulate the type `(int * int) IntMap.t`, there is no way to know outside `DataStr` that is really is a map.

Comment: And I guess that this level of encapsulation does not accomplish much. What do you want to hide to the client code?

Comment: I'd like to just show 'Couples', while hiding 'int2couple' and possibly 'couple', since I created them just to use them `dataStr.ml`. There's no particular reason for what I'm trying to obtain, aside from interface readability.

Comment: You can expose `module Couples = struct type t = (int * int) IntMap.t end` in that case.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I'd like to avoid repeating statements like `(int * int) IntMap.t` in both definition (`dataStr.ml`) and interface (`dataStr.mli`), but I guess it's the only option. It still lets me write "simpler" interfaces for files using these kinds of Maps, like `val use : int -> Couples.t -> Couples.t`.
You can merge your comments in an answer if you like, I will mark it as best. I don't really believe that some other solution will come up. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can't do that. You always have redundancy between ml and mli files on the module types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there is no way to avoid redundancy between interface (mli file) and implementation (ml files) when instantiating a functor.

The best you can do is the following:

`$ cat dataStr.mli:`

```
module IntMap : Map.S with type key = int
type couple = int * int
type int2couple = couple IntMap.t
module Couples : sig type t = int2couple end
```

`$ cat dataStr.ml:`

```
module IntOrder =
  struct
      type t = int
      let compare = Pervasives.compare
  end

module IntMap = Map.Make( IntOrder )

type couple = int * int
type int2couple = couple IntMap.t
module Couples = struct type t = int2couple end
```